# Storing floats in the app delegate

Tags: objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate, cgfloat

I store some floats in my app delegate, then synthesise it in the .m of the app delegate.

Now when I come to use that float in one view controller I do this:

```
del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
CGFloat PUEresult = (*(del.FacilitiesLoad) / *(del.ItLoad));
```

(ItLoad and FacilititesLoad are both the floats stored in my delegate)

Now in the next controller I do the same thing:

```
CGFloat localPUE = (*(del.FacilitiesLoad) / *(del.ItLoad));
```

That always returns inf why is this and how do I stop it doing this?

I've not been working with obj-c for long so be nice please.

Removing pointers does this:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGFloat *' (aka 'float *') and
>   'CGFloat *')

Comment: Why are all those asterisks there?

Comment: Please share the definition of FacilitiesLoad and ItLoad - but I have a feeling that the answer will include removing some asterisk (you are treating those two properties as pointers - but they are likely just float values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGFloat` is a primitive type, no needs to use `*` symbol. Try to remove it in all places where you use CGFloat and check result again

Don't forget to cast youp app delegate to your type:

```
del = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: Does defenition of those variables (in .h) has `*` as well?

Comment: @dev6546, Don't forget to cast youp app delegate to your type

Comment: Also, don't declare your properties as `(strong)`, only `(assign)` - scalars cannot be retained (that is what `strong` pointers mean).